# tftp does not copy files from server, showing 0 bytes

Tags: networking, server, tftp

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, and I have install tftpd-hpa following this
[guide](https://linuxhint.com/install_tftp_server_ubuntu/).

Config file:

```
# /etc/default/tftpd-hpa

TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/tftp"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure --create"
```

tftp server is also running:

```
/usr/sbin/in.tftpd --listen --user tftp --address 0.0.0.0:69 --secure --create /tftp

ngadre@in01-7h4wrf3:/srv$ netstat -plnu
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:69              0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

There are no iptable rules as iptables -vnL is empty.

When I try to test it:

```
ksa200@ksa200:/tmp$ tftp 10.110.234.6
tftp> verbose
Verbose mode on.
tftp> get xv38_xe58-6.6.0.1-a0.cimg
getting from 10.110.234.6:xv38_xe58-6.6.0.1-a0.cimg to xv38_xe58-6.6.0.1-a0.cimg [netascii]
tftp> quit
```

The file size is 0 bytes.
Not sure what is wrong with my configuration. Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with permissions to the file and the directory.
I ran the tftp server with `TFTP_USERNAME="root"`, and `TFTP_DIRECTORY="/home/ngadre/tftp"`, then restarted daemon. After which file transfer is happening as expected.